# css not working in Vue.js single file component

Tags: css, vue.js, vuejs2

I assume this should work but I'm clearly making a mistake (the class in question is `scrollable-modal-body`). I have included the relevant parts of the component :

```
<template>
  <div id="col-md-12">
    <template v-if="showFinancingModal">
    <transition name="modal">
    <div class="modal-mask">
    <div class="modal-wrapper">
      <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-wide" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
          <div class="modal-header">
            <h5 class="modal-title">Financing</h5>
            <div class="float-right hide-modal" @click = "willHideFinancingModal">x</div>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-body scrollable-modal-body">
          ......

</template>
<script>
.....
</script>
<style scoped>
.scrollable-modal-body{
  overflow-y: scroll;
  height:400px;
}
</style>
```

Comment: What does the rendered html look like, is `modal-body` getting the `scrollable-modal-body[data-v-xyz]` class or just `scrollable-modal-body`. Do you have css rules for `modal-body` in a parent that would be affecting it?

Comment: The CSS should be inlined somewhere in your HTML. Please verify that there is actually a `.scrollable-modal-body` class inlined or that the CSS is even being set at all.